# Prove the sequence $a_n =\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot…\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot…\cdot2n}$ has a limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I have several questions to ask:

1) Show increasing, find the upper bound if you can of
 $\sqrt{(n^2-1)}/n$.

$\sqrt{(n^2-1)}/n= |n|\sqrt{1-1/n^2}/n$ if $n$ is positive than $\sqrt1$ else $-\sqrt1$;

bound: $\sqrt{(n^2-1)}/n \le \sqrt {n^2}/n = |n|/n=1$

To show if it is increasing should I do $\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}}{n+1} \ge \frac{\sqrt{(n)^2-1}}{n}$?

2)Prove the sequence $a_n = \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot…\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot…\cdot2n}$ has a limit

$a_n$ is a decreasing sequence, so to have a limit it must be bounded from below.

$a_n = (1-1/2)(1-1/4)…(1-1/2n)$

Comment: If you have several questions to ask, it is better to ask separate questions, unless the questions are closely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-multiplication yields, for $k\ge1$,
$$
\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)^2\le\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)^2
&\le\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k-1}{2k}=0
$$

---

For $n\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}n}{\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}}{n+1}}
&=\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)^3(n-1)}{n^3(n+2)}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{n^4+2n^3-2n-1}{n^4+2n^3}}\\[18pt]
&\lt1
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}n$ is increasing. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac1{n^2}}\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

$$a_n=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot…\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot…\cdot2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}$$

then we can use Stirling's approximation.

Refer to the related

- [What is the limit of $\frac{\prod Odd}{\prod Even}?!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693377/505767)

Comment: Can you help with the other two?

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan The second one is trivial indeed $\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{n\cdot n\ldots n}{1\cdot 2\cdot n}$ or by ratio test for example.

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan I don't understand the first question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta $$
is quite clearly decreasing and convergent to zero (by the dominated convergence theorem).
Laplace's method gives $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is decreasing and bounded below by 0. That's why it has a limit.